# Controlling the position of a single axis in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have the following code plotting a 3D Normal distribution. The data for this normal distribution is saved in the table 'GaussData'. I want to view the plot from a specific angle so I can be consistent across multiple plots, however when I set the ViewVector to what I want the axis are not where I want them. This code:

```
n = 5;
GaussData = 
  Table[{ii, jj, Exp[-(ii^2 + jj^2)]}, {ii, -n, n, 0.1}, {jj, -n, n, 
    0.1}];
Dimensions[GaussData]
GaussData = 
  ArrayReshape[GaussData, {Dimensions[GaussData][[1]]^2, 3}];
plot = ListPlot3D[GaussData, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> cf, Boxed -> False, 
   BaseStyle -> texStyle, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.9], 
   Ticks -> {{-5, 0, 5}, {-5, 0, 5}, {-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {{-6, 6, -0.1}}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0.5}];

 Show[plot, ImageSize -> 600, ViewVector -> {{-50, 20, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

produces the attached image, where the x-axis meets the z-axis at the smallest z value, whereas the y-axis meets the z-axis at the largest z value. Can I specify exaclty where I want each axis to be positioned?

[image]

Comment: Please post all data and code necessary to produce the plots.

Comment: the option you want, I think, is [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html)

Comment: I have added data for the plots. I have also tried AxesEdge, but it didn't work for me

Comment: What exactly is texStyle?

Comment: Where do you want the axes?

Comment: It's difficult to know what to suggest without knowing where you want the axes exactly, but try e.g. `AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}` or `AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}`. you can play around with $\pm 1$'s until it works—unless you want something else?

Comment: Oh thank you, AxesEdge was what I needed I just was using it wrong previously. Thank you!!

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it arises due to a simple mistake with the command AxesEdge,